# Expected: ',', received: ']' AWS SSM RunShellScript

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, runcommand

I want to update many instances, so I have made a script with this command:

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "$y" --document-name AWS-RunShellScript --parameters commands='yum -y update; needs-restarting -r; if \[ $? -eq 1 \]; then exit 194' --cloud-watch-output-config "CloudWatchOutputEnabled=true"
```

Instead of running the command on the machines specified by $y, it says:
`Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Expected: ',', received: ']' for input: commands=yum -y update; needs-restarting -r; if \[ 252 -eq 1 \]; then exit 194; else exit 0; fi`

Note that the `$?` is referenced as 252 for some reason.

Comment: Does the bash commands work when you execute them manually?

Comment: Yes it works locally. If I run the command, it exits the terminal.

Comment: (I'm not running amazon linux which has the needs-restarting utility).

Comment: `$?` expanding to `252` suggests the command is going through some sort of preprecessing/additional parsing step before it's executed. Is it being sent over `ssh`, stored in a variable, or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting double quotes around the value for `--parameters`:

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "$y" --document-name AWS-RunShellScript --parameters "commands='yum -y update; needs-restarting -r; if \[ $? -eq 1 \]; then exit 194'" --cloud-watch-output-config "CloudWatchOutputEnabled=true"
```

See the examples in the [aws-cli reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html).